# VS2013 generates wsdl as https with failing certificate for http wcf service and then fails to generate the client with svcutil.exe

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, wsdl, .net-4.5, webservice-client

I ran into peculiar issue, wcf service then ran in debug mode on VS2013 on http generates links and  wsdl over https that run on different port.
[image]

If i try to go to `http://localhost:53769/WebPricingService.svc?wsdl` it runs for a several minutes and fails eventually.

I couldn't care less about this but it fails when I try to generate the client with `svcutil.exe` with following messages
[image]

I have `mex` added to configuration

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="wsServiceBehavior" name="Corp.WebServices.WebPricingService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsEndpointBinding" name="ConveyancingEndpoint" contract="Corp.Core.Interfaces.IWebPricingService"/>
  <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

binding

```
 <binding name="wsEndpointBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

**Why is it running wsdl on different port and protocol?** **Is there an easy workaround to generate client?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself.

Part where I ask why does it run of different port is simply put - me being stupid. http and https cannot run on same port simultaneously.

To generate client go to `http://localhost:53769/WebPricingService.svc?singleWsdl` then in your browser `File -> Save As...` and save it in `C:/` as `someName.wsdl` then open VS tools and run `svcutil.exe c:\someName.wsdl` this should get you the client named `someName.cs` in some directory for me it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64`.